# Kubectl not working when AKS API authorized ranges are in place

Tags: azure, azure-aks, kubernetes-apiserver

We're implementing security on our k8s cluster in Azure (managed Kubernetes - AKS).
Cluster is deployed via ARM template, the configuration is as following:
1 node, availability set, Standard load balancer, Nginx-based ingress controller, a set of application ddeployed.
According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/api-server-authorized-ip-ranges) we've updated cluster to protect API server from the whole internet:

```
    az aks update --resource-group xxxxxxxx-xxx-xx-xx-xx-x -n xx-xx-xxx-aksCluster 
--api-server-authorized-ip-ranges XX.XX.X.0/24,XX.XX.X.0/24,XX.XXX.XX.0/24,XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32 
--subscription xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx
```

Operation is completed successfully.

When trying to grab logs from the pod the follwoing error is occured:

```
    kubectl get pods -n lims-dev

    NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    XXXX-76df44bc6d-9wdxr             1/1     Running   0          14h

    kubectl logs XXXXX-76df44bc6d-9wdxr -n lims-dev

    Error from server: Get https://aks-agentpool-XXXXXX-1:10250/containerLogs/XXXX/XXXXX-
76df44bc6d-9wdxr/listener: dial tcp 10.22.0.35:10250: i/o timeout
```

When trying to deploy using Azure DevOps, the same error is raised:

```
            2020-04-07T04:49:49.0409528Z ##[error]Error: error installing: 
    Post https://xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-akscluster-dns-xxxxxxx.hcp.eastus2.azmk8s.io:443
/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments: 
dial tcp XX.XX.XXX.142:443: i/o timeout
```

Of course, the subnet where I'm running the kubectl is added to authorized range.
I'm trying to understand what's the source of the problem.

Comment: Do you put public IP of the machine where you run the command in the api-server-authorized-ip-ranges? Also does the Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

You need also to specify `--load-balancer-outbound-ips` parameter once creating AKS cluster. This IP will be used by your pods to communicate to external world, as well as to AKS API server. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/api-server-authorized-ip-ranges#specify-the-outbound-ips-for-the-standard-sku-load-balancer)

Comment: Thanks, but we had implemented it on and already existed cluster.